# asp.net mvc + activerecord saving object graph

Tags: asp.net-mvc, activerecord, castle-activerecord, crud

I'm using asp.net mvc and I'm trying to create a new Employee, in my form I use the Html.DropDown(...) to display a list of Departments to select from.

Ideally I would like MVC to just figure out which Department was selected (Id property is the value in dropdown), fetch it and set it in the incoming Employee object. instead I get a null value and I have to fetch the Department myself using the Request.Form[...].

I saw an example here: http://blog.rodj.org/archive/2008/03/31/activerecord-the-asp.net-mvc-framework.aspx but that doesn't seem to work with asp.net mvc beta

This is basic CRUD with a well-proven ORM.... need it really be so hard?

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: yup code would be a good idea, I'm not sure I understand the problem fully.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC does not know how to translate the DepartmentId form value to a Department.Load(DepartmentId) call.  To do this you need to implement a binder for your model.

```
[ActiveRecord("Employees")]
[ModelBinder(EmployeeBinder]
public class Employee : ActiveRecordBase<Employee>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [BelongsTo(NotNull = true)]
    public Department Department
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The EmployeeBinder is responsible for turning route/form data into an object.

```
public class EmployeeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    #region IModelBinder Members

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // ...

        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("DepartmentId"))
        {
            // The Department Id was passed, call find
            employee.Department = Department.Find(Convert.ToInt32(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["DepartmentId"]));
        }
        // ...
    }

    #endregion
}
```

With this in place anytime an Employee is used as a parameter for an action the binder will be called.

```
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
        // Do stuff with your bound and loaded employee object!
    }
```

See [This blog post for further information](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/08/29/how-to-use-the-asp-net-mvc-modelbinder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I [ported ARFetch to ASP.NET MVC](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/02/arfetch-for-aspnet-mvc.html) a couple of weeks ago... maybe that could help you.